# “Selling In-App products” or “Play Billing Library”?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I've found in android developer page two tutorials to use billing with Android: [Selling In-App products](https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/index.html) and  [Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/training/play-billing-library/index.html)

Why Google have provided both ways to work with in-app billing? Which one google recommend to use with Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

The first tutorial you are referencing ([Selling In-App products](https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/index.html)) was the original method. Last year Google created the [Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html) as a wrapper to simplify the implementation.

As they explain in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html):

- The library is a wrapper for the Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL) file that defines the interface to the In-app Billing service. You can use the Play Billing Library to simplify your development process, allowing you to focus your effort on implementing logic specific to your app, such as displaying in-app products and purchasing items.
- If you are integrating the In-app Billing service in your app using an alternative language such as C++, or you want to interact directly with the AIDL file, see [Implementing In-app Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html).

In other words:

- If your project is a standard Java/Kotlin app, the [Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html) is the preferred method, as it will simplify your implementation.
- If you are using C++ or for some reason need to access the AIDL file, use the old method.